# XCode8, Swift 2.3 - dequeue reusableCellWithIdentifier breaking with Accessibility Inspector on

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8

Device/Environment information: I'm running on an MBP with XCode 8 GM, building on Swift 2.3 to an iPad Air 2 simulator running iOS 9.2. This same behavior manifests on other simulators, and did not manifest on XCode 7.

More curiously, I had four consecutive passes of this test before the first failure, and it has failed consistently (n>20) since. I'm not sure what changed, since I was working on a different issue, but I could plausibly have purged DerivedData and/or Pods and then rebuilt.

In the app, there's a CommentsViewController which dequeues CommentsTableViewCells in a totally standard way with a nib that's registered to a variable (`reuseIdentifier`) that is used to dequeue the cells. This file has not changed in a substantial amount of time.

This is the registration of the Nib:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

And this is the dequeueing of the TableViewCell:

```
CommentsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

When running the app normally, everything is totally fine. However, if the XCUITest framework is asked to take a Snapshot of the UI Hierarchy or the Accessibility Inspector is turned on in the Simulator and the dequeued cell is interacted with, the app crashes with the following message in the log, with the name of the app removed:

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UITableView.m:6564
>   2016-09-12 16:22:28.666 [26852:512611] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Comment - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a323e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109d9cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a323cca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000104c534de -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
>       4   UIKit                               0x0000000107b11a8d -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 266
>       5   UIKit                               0x0000000119bd41ba -[UITableViewAccessibility dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 183
>       6                               0x0000000101ae1766 -[CommentsViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 214
>       7   UIKit                               0x0000000107b24e43 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 766
>       8   UIKit                               0x0000000107b24f7b -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000107af9a39 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2996
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000107b0b930 -[UITableView _visibleCells] + 27
>       11  UIKit                               0x0000000119bd361a -[UITableViewAccessibility accessibilityElementsHidden] + 197
>       12  MapKitFramework                     0x000000011bd8d2a1 -[MKUITableViewAccessibility accessibilityElementsHidden] + 64
>       13  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d4c103 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityPrivate) _accessibilityViewIsVisibleIgnoringAXOverrides:] + 74
>       14  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d2838e -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityShouldBeProcessed:] + 32
>       15  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d277fd -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilitySubviewsForGettingElementsWithOptions:] + 1950
>       16  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27ce8 -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 632
>       17  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       18  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       19  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       20  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       21  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       22  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d27d5a -[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _addAccessibilityElementsAndOrderedContainersWithOptions:toCollection:] + 746
>       23  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d28178 +[UIView(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityElementsAndContainersDescendingFromViews:options:sorted:] + 399
>       24  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d28570 -[UIApplication(UIAccessibilityElementTraversal) _accessibilityViewChildrenWithOptions:referenceWindow:] + 116
>       25  UIKit                               0x0000000119bc8765 -[UIApplicationAccessibility _accessibilitySummaryElement] + 90
>       26  UIKit                               0x0000000119bc5d51 -[UIApplicationAccessibility _accessibilityResponderElement:] + 1852
>       27  UIKit                               0x0000000119c0b939 -[UIResponder(UITextAccessibilityUtilities) _accessibilityHasTextOperations] + 31
>       28  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d3546d -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:] + 4378
>       29  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d4ee9d _accessibilityAttributesForObject + 333
>       30  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d4ea77 -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotDescendantsWithAttributes:maxDepth:maxChildren:maxArrayCount:] + 553
>       31  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d4fa1a -[NSObject(UIAccessibilityAutomation) _accessibilityUserTestingSnapshotWithOptions:] + 594
>       32  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d3308f -[NSObject(AXPrivCategory) accessibilityAttributeValue:forParameter:] + 3533
>       33  UIAccessibility                     0x0000000119d20393 _copyParameterizedAttributeValueCallback + 176
>       34  AXRuntime                           0x0000000119db2529 _AXXMIGCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 312
>       35  AXRuntime                           0x0000000119dad02f _XCopyParameterizedAttributeValue + 466
>       36  AXRuntime                           0x0000000119dba3a7 mshMIGPerform + 235
>       37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a24fca9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 41
>       38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a24fc19 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 473
>       39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a245390 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
>       40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a244828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
>       41  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010cab5ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
>       42  UIKit                               0x00000001079cb610 UIApplicationMain + 171
>       43                              0x0000000101883f2a main + 2234
>       44  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010aef292d start + 1
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

This is very awkward, because I have tests that passed this morning and now don't pass. I've done a search for similar problems but they're all at a minimum several years old and the answers revolve around issues with UINibs or IB that don't exist or workarounds that involve IB UI components that don't exist anymore (well, or assume that the nib isn't registered).

So, my question is, **why is this crashing only when the Accessibility Hierarchy is being interacted with**, and **How can I fix it, so that my tests can go back to working?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest XCode 8.1 Beta with the 10.1 simulators, so the answer to "How can I fix it" turned out to be "Wait".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try change the `nil` in the `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];` to `[NSBundle mainBundle]`?

Comment: I'm not sure why that would potentially fix it, but I tried it anyway and it didn't fix it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CommentsTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];` be executed before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

In my case,`cellForRowAtIndexPath` be called before `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I set some breakpoints, and the `registerNib` line in `viewDidLoad` is definitely triggering its breakpoint before the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` line is triggering its breakpoint, which seems like the correct behavior.